# AYUDA POR FAVOR Suma de elementos de una matriz

Tags: windows-forms, matrices

soy estudiante de ingeniería informática y me acaban de dejar un ejercicio el cual me esta dando varios problemas resolverlo, tengo que crear una matriz de 4x5 en windows forms y desplegar todos los elementos de esta, hasta aqui todo bien pero ademas de hacer esto tengo que realizar la suma de los elemento que se encuentran en los renglones pares y encontrar el elemento mayor de la columna de enmedio, aqui les dejo lo que llevo de antemano gracias.

```
    {
        int R, C;

        int[,] numeros = new int[4, 5] { { 10, 45, 7, 23, 13 }, { 8, 76, 11, 58, 14 }, { 12, 55, 43, 32, 15 }, { 73, 99, 44, 2, 16 } };
        for (R = 0; R < 4; R++)
        {
            for (C = 0; C < 5; C++)

            {
                txtnumeros.Text += numeros[R, C] + "\t";
            }`
```

Comment: Recorda que podes verificar si un número es par usando el operador `%`, por ejemplo, `6%2` devuelve `0` (el módulo), si el resultado es 0, implica que el número es par, caso contrario... Espero que puedas aplicar esto a tu problema

Answer (score 0):

La matriz empieza con indice 0, asi que para el ojo humano el 1 y el 3 son los renglones par. Teniendo esto en cuenta creamos nuestra guarda:

```
for (R = 0; R < 4; R++)
{
   bool esPar = R == 1 || R == 3; // si la matriz no cambia el tamaño
   esPar = R + 1 % 2 == 0; // para cualquier tamaño
   //...
```

Luego en el bucle de las columnas sumamos al valor de las columnas

```
   //...
   for (C = 0; C < 5; C++)
   {
       if(esPar)
       {
           // asumimos result como int[] result = {0, 0 , 0, 0, 0}
           // declarado en el contexto de la variable numeros
           result[C] = result[C] + numeros[R, C]; `
```

De esta manera guardamos el valor de la suma de los elementos de cada columna de todas las filas pares en un array result.

Ahora bien, para calcular el mayor elemento de la columna del medio hay que hacer un 'lock' a la columna del medio:

```
int indiceMedio = TotalColumnas / 2;
```

y en el bucle de las columnas hacer la operación, que no corresponde hacerlo (tampoco el ejercicio anterior) porque es trabajo para el alumno, tendrian que conversarlo con el profesor jeje.

Pero la idea de este ejercicio es aprender a recorrer intuitivamente una matriz asi que aqui unos tips.

- En una matriz de RxC la orientación la determina el anidado de los bucles R->C derecha a izquierda, C->R arriba abajo y asi:
- La operaciones con la celda actual se realizan en el cuerpo del bucle interior.
- Cuando calculamos promedios u otras operaciones de ese tipo debemos tener acceso al tamaño la matriz asi que nos combiene guardar en una variable ej: int totalColumas = 5.